# How to extract this attribute using jQuery ($(this) puts it in an array/square brackets)

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamic html I generate, when I do $(this) and console log it I get the following (in square brackets):

```
  <td groupid="146"><div class="tt" style="width:64px; height:22px; margin:0 auto"></div></td>
```

From $(this) alone how can I get the value of groupid?

Comment: Which node does `this` (or `$(this)`) represent?

Comment: How do you get console.log ($(this)) to print like that?

Comment: Presumably the OP is doing console.log($(this)) and then clicking on the link that it generates, which (in Firebug at least) takes him to the HTML view, where he could then copy/paste something like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is returning an array of elements. $(this)[0] will return the element, or
`$(this).attr('groupid');` the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children('td').attr('groupid');
```

Comment: That would find the groupid of all TDs (directly) inside $(this) ... but it wouldn't find $(this), which itself is a TD.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).attr('groupid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(this).attr('groupid');
```

The square brackets indicates a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupId = $(this).attr(groupid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children("td").attr("groupid")
```

or a `.find()` instead of `.children()` maybe

Answer (score 0):

$(this) refers to what you've just selected.

So if you selected:

```
$('div.tt').each(function() {
    //$(this) refers to the div with .tt class
    var groupID = $(this).parents('td').attr('groupid');
});
```

and if you selected the td itself:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    //$(this) refers to the td element
    var groupID = $(this).attr('groupid');
});
```

Comment: since the correct answer is so simple, this solution is truly amazing ;)

Comment: lol thank you for that... its just that the question used to ask what $(this) refers to.